# Sparkle framework downloads and updates but actually not

Tags: macos, cocoa, sparkle

I've integrated Sparkle framework into my Cocoa app (MacOS X 10.9.5). 
While testing updates, Sparkle reports that there is an update available (i'm using this [appcast](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/peetonn/ndncon/master/releases/Appcast.xml)), downloads it and restarts the app. However upon launching I still have old version of the app.
What could be the problem?

Here are the logs from console during update:

```
2014-10-09 16:45:20.946 NdnCon[14647:507] Sparkle: ===== NdnCon.app =====
2014-10-09 16:45:21.491 NdnCon[14647:507] Invalid color System, labelColor (warning given only once)
2014-10-09 16:45:26.824 NdnCon[14647:14203] Sparkle: Extracting /Users/peetonn/Library/Application Support/NdnCon/.Sparkle/NdnCon 2/v0.1.1.zip using 'ditto -x -k - "$DESTINATION"'
2014-10-09 16:45:32.548 NdnCon[14647:507] Sparkle: The host app is not signed using Apple Code Signing, and therefore cannot verify updates this way. Sparkle will use DSA signature instead.
2014-10-09 16:45:32.618 NdnCon[14647:507] terminating...
```

Comment: have you checked the version number of the application, which has been uploaded to appcast?